# Radically different timings for an action on PHP/MySQL setup

Tags: php, mysql, performance

First of all, thanks to all of you whose answers I have read in the past on many subjects! :)

As you'll no doubt realize, I'm not knowledgeable in performance optimisations, so am looking for help on the subject.

I'm running an application on PHP/MySQL server (Windows, Zend Server) and one thing I've noticed while doing timing measurements on different actions is that sometimes I get huge variations in timing when repeating the same action several times. (and it's not that the second time is much faster, which could be explained by caching - it seems very random).

**Edit:**
These multiple measurements are done in the exact same user condition every time: same user, same PC, same browser, same application, same query. Timing is measured from a user perspective: start on user click, stop when the page display is finished.

The query in question (one example among others) is actually a succession of many queries. The functionality is to display an array where columns = days of the week, rows = list of activities. Here is a partial list:

```
SELECT * FROM sheettime WHERE idUser=305 AND `date` = '201409'
select * from activity where activity.id=3209 and activity.idProject=892
select id from origin where refId =3209 and refType ='Activity'
select id from planningelement where refId =3209 and refType ='Activity'
select * from planningelement where id=5232
SELECT * FROM sheettime WHERE idUser=305 AND `date` = '201409'
select * from activity where activity.id=6901 and activity.idProject=892
select id from origin where refId =6901 and refType ='Activity'
select * from origin where id=2155
select id from planningelement where refId =6901 and refType ='Activity'
select * from planningelement where id=11785
SELECT * FROM sheettime WHERE idUser=305 AND `date` = '201409'
SELECT * FROM  work WHERE idResource=305 AND `workdate` = '2014-09-01'
SELECT * FROM  work WHERE idResource=305 AND `workdate` = '2014-09-02'
SELECT * FROM  work WHERE idResource=305 AND `workdate` = '2014-09-03'
SELECT * FROM  work WHERE idResource=305 AND `workdate` = '2014-09-04'
SELECT * FROM  work WHERE idResource=305 AND `workdate` = '2014-09-05'
SELECT * FROM  work WHERE idResource=305 AND `workdate` = '2014-09-06'
SELECT * FROM  work WHERE idResource=305 AND `workdate` = '2014-09-07'
```

(the full list of queries being sent to the DB for this particular user action is about 5000 - no laughing !!)

Note that I do plan to tackle the problem of the number of queries, but right now I would first like to understand the variations in timing for the same user action.
**** end edit ****

I can do a simple action which will take 3 seconds the first time, and get stuck for 20 seconds another time...

So I'm just wondering if you have any ideas as to what could cause this type of thing / what direction to search in ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a specific, reproducible example. There's a million different possible reasons for performance differences. Hardware,  operating system, library versions, configuration, caching, etc. pp.

Comment: @lxg Hmm, yeah, that's indeed my big problem: I'm having trouble getting info specific enough to be relevant.
To be clear, I'm using the exact same user setup for all these measured actions (application accessed via Chrome, using the same PC, same user).
The action in question is a SELECT, and doing the exact same query every time.
To be honest, I'd be happy with just getting some ideas for where to start looking, knowing that I can't change the HW, OS, or event the application, but could tweak server configuration (caching settings?).
Does that help, or just too vague ?

Comment: So, to be clear, you're testing on the same machine, with the same OS, the same applications, the same configurations? That would be a good starting point. Now, an example query would be nice. Could you please update your post accordingly? It is really essential that you provide more information about your setup, especially some code would be good. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: @lxg Edited the question with added details. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @derp OK, guess it's too vague as it is. I'll definitely try to check the slow query log as a starting point, and in any case try to target more specific performance issues. Thanks for taking the time to answer.